# Append to Excel 2010 List

Tags: excel, vba

I have two lists that I need to compare and have a resulting list with all values and no duplicates. I've been trying to write this in VBA and without the knowledge of how long each comparable column will be.

Ex:

```
Recent_ID    Prior_ID
76000        76000
76010        76300 
76020        76020

Result should be:
76000
76010
76020
76300
```

I see a lot of other posts about this subject but I can't seem to find one that has a good and generic answer.

Comment: Do you need a VBA solution for this or would a simple user-driven solution work? 'Cause you could always copy and paste `Prior_ID`s below `Recent_ID`s, then highlight the whole list and use the `Data -> Remove Duplicates` feature...

Comment: I guess there is no reason that I couldn't just make that a part of the instructions... I guess that could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friendly neighborhood search engine told me that this VBA code should probably do what you want without too much trouble.

http://mrspreadsheets.com/1/post/2012/08/vba-code-snippet-16-combine-two-columns-into-one-and-remove-duplicates.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I did a lot of searching myself but wasn't able to find anything like this. Thanks!